# Why does my array in MATLAB saturate at a value of 255?

Tags: matlab

This is my code:

```
arr = zeros(fx-10,1);
frm = frams(x).cdata;
for k=1:fx-10
    for i=1:10
        for j=1:fy
            arr(k) = arr(k)+ abs(frm(k+i-1,j)-model(i,j))
        end
    end
end
```

Why the array receive only up to 255 value?

I try to define:

```
 arr = zeros(fx-10,1,'int64');
```

and the code failed:

> ??? Undefined function or method
>   'plus' for input arguments of type
>   'int64'.

Comment: can you provide us with the output of `whos arr frm model`

Comment: What release of MATLAB? Non-double math has been in MATLAB for a while, but not forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although your array `arr` is of type double, I believe that one or more of the values you are getting from `frm` or `model` is of type [UINT8](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uint8.html), which has a maximum value of 255. When the arithmetic is done to add these values to `arr`, I believe the calculation is done using integer arithmetic and the result is converted to a double to be placed in `arr`. As you keep adding UINT8 values together, the value eventually saturates at the maximum 255.

To get around this, you can use the function [DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/double.html) to convert values from `frm` or `model` to type double before doing the arithmetic. Something like this should work:

```
arr(k) = arr(k) + abs(double(frm(k+i-1,j))-double(model(i,j)));
```

Comment: Thank you
It helped me very much